# why this x path brings just one value?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

this is my x path

```
normalize-space(.//li[@class='amenities_details']/span[normalize-space(.)='Amenities:']/following-sibling::span[1]/ul//li/span/div/@title)
```

and this is the html

[image]

I get just the `Balcony` even though i put `//` before the `li`, what should I do to get all the text that are inside the ul please? (I need them in a list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *don't normalize space*:

```
>>> response.xpath(".//li[@class='amenities_details']/span[normalize-space(.)='Amenities:']/following-sibling::span[1]/ul//li/span/div/@title").extract()
[u'Balcony', u'Pets Allowed', u'Gymnasium', u'Children\u2019s play area', u'Mosque', u'Shared swimming pool', u'24 hours Maintenance', u'Basement parking', u'Central air conditioning', u'Basketball Court']
```

Comment: Thank you it works, please is this off-topic? why they close the question ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli don't worry about that - I personally think your question is clear and has everything needed to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from not normalizing space what alecxe mentioned, you can further simplify your xpath expression.

```
//li[@class='amenities_details' and span[contains(text(), 'Amenities:')]]//ul/li/span/div/@title
```

also gives the expected output:

```
[u'Balcony', u'Pets Allowed', u'Gymnasium', u'Children\u2019s play area', u'Mosque', u'Shared swimming pool', u'24 hours Maintenance', u'Basement parking', u'Central air conditioning', u'Basketball Court']
```